# Acceder a un archivo desde una custom template wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$filename = "example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/frases.txt";


    if(!file_exists($filename)){
        echo "File not exist ";
    }else{echo "exists";}

    $rows = file($filename);
    array_shift($rows);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo $row . "\n";
    }
```

No consigo acceder a un arvhico .txt desde una custom template de wordpress. El archivo no existe y el nombre es correcto. El achivo .txt se encuentra en la misma carpeta que la template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue cambia la ruta, en vez de poner example.com poner la ruta actual:

**./wp-content/themes/theme-child/frases.txt**

```
$filename = "./wp-content/themes/theme-child/frases.txt";


if(!file_exists($filename)){
    echo "File not exist ";
}else{echo "exists";}

$rows = file($filename);
array_shift($rows);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Tenés que diferenciar cuando necesitas usar una uri y cuando un path. Para obtener el path del child-theme podes usar la función: `get_stylesheet_directory() `